# VBA to add databars with three different colors based on a condition

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel report where databars have to be added with three different colors (Red, Amber and Green) based on three different conditions. Following code does that perfectly. However, it removes all the conditional formatting that already exists in the selection. When I comment the line Selection.FormatConditions.Delete, it throws an error "Object doesnt support this property or method' at the line c.FormatConditions(1).Formula = "=if(" & cellName & "<0.8, true, false)"

I will need the existing formatting conditions to be retained. Can you please help?

```
Public Sub AddDataBars()

Selection.FormatConditions.Delete


For Each c In Selection

Dim db As Databar

Set db = c.FormatConditions.AddDatabar
db.ShowValue = True
db.MinPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueNumber, newvalue:=0
db.MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueNumber, newvalue:=1
db.BarColor.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
db.BarColor.TintAndShade = 0
db.BarFillType = xlDataBarFillGradient
db.Direction = xlContext
db.NegativeBarFormat.ColorType = xlDataBarColor
db.BarBorder.Type = xlDataBarBorderNone
db.AxisPosition = xlDataBarAxisAutomatic
db.AxisColor.Color = 0
db.AxisColor.TintAndShade = 0
db.NegativeBarFormat.Color.Color = 255
db.NegativeBarFormat.Color.TintAndShade = 0


Set db = c.FormatConditions.AddDatabar
db.ShowValue = True
db.MinPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueNumber, newvalue:=0
db.MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueNumber, newvalue:=1
db.BarColor.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
db.BarColor.TintAndShade = 0
db.BarFillType = xlDataBarFillGradient
db.Direction = xlContext
db.NegativeBarFormat.ColorType = xlDataBarColor
db.BarBorder.Type = xlDataBarBorderNone
db.AxisPosition = xlDataBarAxisAutomatic
db.AxisColor.Color = 0
db.AxisColor.TintAndShade = 0
db.NegativeBarFormat.Color.Color = 255
db.NegativeBarFormat.Color.TintAndShade = 0


Set db = c.FormatConditions.AddDatabar
db.ShowValue = True
db.MinPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueNumber, newvalue:=0
db.MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueNumber, newvalue:=1
db.BarColor.Color = RGB(255, 130, 130)
db.BarColor.TintAndShade = 0
db.BarFillType = xlDataBarFillGradient
db.Direction = xlContext
db.NegativeBarFormat.ColorType = xlDataBarColor
db.BarBorder.Type = xlDataBarBorderNone
db.AxisPosition = xlDataBarAxisAutomatic
db.AxisColor.Color = 0
db.AxisColor.TintAndShade = 0
db.NegativeBarFormat.Color.Color = 255
db.NegativeBarFormat.Color.TintAndShade = 0

cellName = c.Address

c.FormatConditions(1).Formula = "=if(" & cellName & "<0.8, true, false)"
c.FormatConditions(2).Formula = "=if(AND(" & cellName & ">=0.8, " & cellName    & "<=1.00001), true, false)"
c.FormatConditions(3).Formula = "=if(" & cellName & ">1.00001, true, false)"

Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using? The `.Formula` property doesn't work in Excel 2013.

Comment: I am using Excel 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already selected the cells to add data bars into, you can use this range to add them and then modify each conditional formatting one by one in the same range. Note that the `.FormatConditions` index doesn't change, this is because Excel automatically changes the index once the condition is modified. So, this macro will only work once. Also, this will only work when you have 3 existing formatting conditions in the selected range.

This is what I came up with.

```
Public Sub AddDataBars()
    Dim db As Databar

    Set db = Selection.FormatConditions.AddDatabar
    db.ShowValue = True
    db.MinPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueNumber, newvalue:=0
    db.MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueNumber, newvalue:=1
    db.BarColor.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    db.BarColor.TintAndShade = 0
    db.BarFillType = xlDataBarFillGradient
    db.Direction = xlContext
    db.NegativeBarFormat.ColorType = xlDataBarColor
    db.BarBorder.Type = xlDataBarBorderNone
    db.AxisPosition = xlDataBarAxisAutomatic
    db.AxisColor.Color = 0
    db.AxisColor.TintAndShade = 0
    db.NegativeBarFormat.Color.Color = 255
    db.NegativeBarFormat.Color.TintAndShade = 0

    Set db = Selection.FormatConditions.AddDatabar
    db.ShowValue = True
    db.MinPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueNumber, newvalue:=0
    db.MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueNumber, newvalue:=1
    db.BarColor.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
    db.BarColor.TintAndShade = 0
    db.BarFillType = xlDataBarFillGradient
    db.Direction = xlContext
    db.NegativeBarFormat.ColorType = xlDataBarColor
    db.BarBorder.Type = xlDataBarBorderNone
    db.AxisPosition = xlDataBarAxisAutomatic
    db.AxisColor.Color = 0
    db.AxisColor.TintAndShade = 0
    db.NegativeBarFormat.Color.Color = 255
    db.NegativeBarFormat.Color.TintAndShade = 0

    Set db = Selection.FormatConditions.AddDatabar
    db.ShowValue = True
    db.MinPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueNumber, newvalue:=0
    db.MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueNumber, newvalue:=1
    db.BarColor.Color = RGB(255, 130, 130)
    db.BarColor.TintAndShade = 0
    db.BarFillType = xlDataBarFillGradient
    db.Direction = xlContext
    db.NegativeBarFormat.ColorType = xlDataBarColor
    db.BarBorder.Type = xlDataBarBorderNone
    db.AxisPosition = xlDataBarAxisAutomatic
    db.AxisColor.Color = 0
    db.AxisColor.TintAndShade = 0
    db.NegativeBarFormat.Color.Color = 255
    db.NegativeBarFormat.Color.TintAndShade = 0

    With Selection
        With .FormatConditions(1)
            If .Operator <> xlLess Then
                .Modify xlCellValue, xlLess, "0.8"
            Else
                .Modify xlCellValue, xlGreater, "0.8"
                .Modify xlCellValue, xlLess, "0.8"
            End If
            .StopIfTrue = False
        End With
        With .FormatConditions(1)
            If .Operator <> xlBetween Then
                .Modify xlCellValue, xlBetween, "0.8", "1.00001"
            Else
                .Modify xlCellValue, xlLess, "1.00001"
                .Modify xlCellValue, xlBetween, "0.8", "1.00001"
            End If
            .StopIfTrue = False
        End With
        With .FormatConditions(1)
            If .Operator <> xlGreater Then
                .Modify xlCellValue, xlGreater, "1.00001"
            Else
                .Modify xlCellValue, xlLess, "1.00001"
                .Modify xlCellValue, xlGreater, "1.00001"
            End If
            .StopIfTrue = False
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Before running the macro:
[image: Before running the macro]

After running the macro:
[image: After running the macro]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am not sure if I understood this. Should I add these 3 conditions to the selection before adding data bars through code? Because, I get the error "Object doesnt support this property or method" when I run the code without adding any conditions.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, you do need to initially add 3 formatting conditions for it to work. Adding formatting conditions will produce problems when you run the tool several times as it will keep adding 3 formatting conditions each execution, making your sheet really slow to load. I edited my answer and added that details.